# How to resize image, but keep its proportions with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a "file" input and a function, called by event "onchange". What it does is resizing and showing image, but it's not exactly what I need.

```
<input type="file" id="imgUp" accept=".jpg" onchange="readURL(this);" > 

<script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#avatar,#image')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(70)
                .height(70);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Is it possible to resize(keeping proportions) and show an image using Javascript, without jQuery?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the implicit height and width declarations to max-height and max-width:

`.css('max-width', '70px').css('max-height', '70px');`

Using max height and max width sets the bounding box it should use, and then the image will fit within that at it's native aspect ratio.

Native vanilla JS:

`.style.maxWidth = '70px';`

`.style.maxHeight = '70px';`

If you're wanting to move away from jQuery to vanilla JS (I applaud you for doing so), try [this helpful website](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

Vanilla conversion for your code:

```
$('#avatar,#image')
  .attr('src', e.target.result)
  .width(70)
  .height(70);
};
```

becomes:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#avatar,#image');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i){
  el.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
  el.style.maxWidth = '70px';
  el.style.maxHeight = '70px';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To preserver the aspect ration, you can set only the width or the height of the image instead of setting both of them.

Here is an example:

```
$('#avatar,#image').attr('src', e.target.result).width(70);
```

Or

```
$('#avatar,#image').attr('src', e.target.result).height(70);
```

And in vanilla Javascript:

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("#image, #avatar");
for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
     imgs[i].src = e.target.result;
     imgs[i].width = 70;// or imgs[i].height = 70;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yswry44h/)